# Using Build.VERSION_CODES to deal with deprecation

Tags: android

The WebSettings.setPluginsEnabled (boolean flag) method has been deprecated in favor of setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState) from and beyond API Level 8.

My code needs to run on API Level 6 and above versions of Android and I want to use Build.VERSION_CODES to handle deprecation properly.

My question is: I am forced to use numbers like '7' instead of the Build.VERSION_CODE numbers since obviously ECLAIR_MR1 was only introduced in API Level 7. And I can't compile my code on API Level 6 if I use ECLAIR_MR1 instead of '7'.

Am I just supposed to use digits instead of the Build.VERSION_CODE values?

Comment: "I can't compile my code on API Level 6." Does this mean you are targeting SDK 6? Or your minimum SDK is 6?

Comment: The issue is resolved. I confused myself, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The project is to be built with an appropriate targetSdk.